# Laravel Relationships can't access

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have 3 models: User, A, B and C.

User.php

```
public function a()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\A');
}
```

A.php

```
public function b(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\B');
}
```

B.php

```
public function cRelation(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\C');
}
```

Then, i execute my query and load the relationship

```
$tests = User::all();
$tests->load('a.b.cRelation');
```

Now, in my view file, if i print this:

```
@foreach($tests as $test)
    {{$test->a->b}}
@endforeach
```

I can see my c_relation magic property as expected.
But if i try to access it nothing is printed.

Where am i wrong? Why if i print the parent object (`$test->a->b`), i can see the property but i can't print it?

Comment: how are you trying to access the property? `$test->a->b->cRelation`?

Comment: {{$test->a->b->c_relation}} because while printing {{$test->a->b}} i saw the c_relation property, but now, i tried to access it with {{$test->a->b->cRelation}} and it worked. So, this property is not real. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening...

When you just print a model in your template with `{{ $test->a->b }}`, the model is converted into JSON to make the output more readable.
When converting a model to JSON, Eloquent by default changes the relationship names from *camelCase* to *snake_case*.

However when you access a relationship from the model, you always use the **method name** so in that case `{{ $test->a->b->cRelation }}`